# Sortest well-established "for each" equivialent in a proper class

Tags: notation

There's lots of useful notations that can be used reliably in set notation, such as $\forall_{a\in S} P(a)$, stating that for all $a$ in the set $S$, $P(a)$ is true.  For classes it is not so clear.  It doesn't seem like one can use "for all" in this way.  Instead, I typically see long winded phrasings in the form of "There is a mapping between an element $a$ in class $C$ and a corresponding true predicate $P(a)$.

When writing my notes, I'd like to use a more terse notation.  I could use something like $\forall_{a\in C} P(a)$ as an abbreviation, but I'd like to use something more recognizable.  Historically there's a good reason why we choose the notations we do, and its not always obvious to a neophyte.

**What is the shortest well-established notation for this idea of mapping from any/all elements of a class into other objects?**  (If $\forall$ is used, great!  If not, I'd love to know what is actually used)

Comment: I disagree with the whole premise of the question: the "there is a mapping" phrasing is far more problematic than just "$\forall_{a\in C}P(a)$" or similar. This is because quantification is by default over the whole universe, which (in $\mathsf{ZF}$-land anyways) is a proper class, already! By contrast, a "mapping" between classes isn't a set and so when we say "there is a mapping between $C_1$ and $C_2$" for classes $C_1,C_2$ we are engaging in meaningful abuse of terminology.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If it's helpful, the context is category theory, defining morphisms between categories.  That definition almost always starts with defining a mapping from the objects in one category (the objects being a class) to the objects in another category.  For instance, they may construct a mapping from the product ('red', x) to ('blue', x), via $(x, y) \mapsto ('blue', y)$.  But before they can say that, they have to phrase it in terms of the elements of the original product category, and thus the original class of objects.  I typically see that step done in words.

Comment: The whole point of category theory is defining these concepts on categories, so I see no issue there.  But they seem to build on presumptions about what can and cannot be done to the classes of objects that make up the category.  I've had trouble finding notation for that, other than full natural language sentences.